# Create a list of tuples in OPL with scripting based on conditions

Tags: cplex, opl

I'm trying to write a script in OPL that will take a nxm matrix of 1s and 0s, and return for each n, the corresponding m where the value is 1.

Let's say I've defined my data like this:

```
col = {"r1","r2","r3"};
row = {"s1","s2"};
value = [   [1 0 1]
            [1 0 0]];
```

My code looks like this right now:

```
{string} row = ...;
{string} col = ...;
float value[row][col] = ...;
{string} t = {};

tuple P {
  string id;
  {string} list;

{P} myPs;

execute {
  for (var i in row) {
    t.clear();
    var id = i;
    for (var j in col) {
        if (value [i][j] == 1)
            {t.add(j);}
    }
    myPs.add(id, t);;
  }    
  writeln(myPs);
}
```

I'm trying to get the result to be:

```
{   <"s1" {"r1" "r3"}>
    <"s2" {"r1"}>}
```

Right now, the result of myPS is:

```
{   <"s1" {"r1"}>
    <"s2" {"r1"}>}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the model I'd rather write

```
{string} row = ...;
{string} col = ...;
float value[row][col] = ...;


tuple P {
  string id;
  {string} list;
}

{string} listPerId[id in row]={j | j  in col: value[id][j] == 1};

{P} myPs={<id,listPerId[id]> | id in row};

execute {
writeln(myPs);
}
```

which gives

```
{<"s1" {"r1" "r3"}> <"s2" {"r1"}>}
```